# Падеж ( винительный или родительный)

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Кошка родила пушистых котят.  Какой падеж - пушистых котят? Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

***Родила*** (кого?) ***котят***.

Какой падеж у словоформы ***котят*** — родительный или винительный?

При анализе подобных предложений сомнительную словоформу следует заменить на **одушевлённое существительное женского рода, II склонения, единственного числа:**

*Родила кошечк**у** / девочк**у** / дочк**у**.*

Флексия ***-у*** однозначно указывает на **винительный падеж**.

Answer (score 0):

Кошка родила пушистых котят. Это **винительный падеж.**

Чтобы определить падеж (Р.п. или В.п.), можно составить сочетание глагол + сущ. ж.р. ед.ч., например "родить девочку", тогда ясно, что это В.п. (окончание У В.п. не совпадает с окончанием А Р.п.).